# prettyPhoto not working in my wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

So friends I am trying to use prettyPhoto in my wordpress theme but its not working at all. Both of its files - prettyPhoto.css and jquery.prettyPhoto.js are correctly linked in  header.php file.

This is the linking of the files in my header.php file -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Please let me know if this problem is due to not using wp_enqueue_script().

And this is how I link the image to be used with prettyPhoto -

```
<a title="test image" href="images/new-image.png" rel="prettyPhoto[]"><img src="images/new-image.png" alt="Some Alternate Text" /></a>
```

When I click on image, it doesn't open in prettyPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

Have you built a custom theme to get it working. If so there may be other dependencies on files like header.php index.php or footer.php which may cause it not to work. Switch to default twenty eleven theme and see how it goes. If it works there, thenm there is something wrong with your theme files , may be footer.php or index.php et-al.

Comment: what could be wrong with footer.php or index.php file, if I have to put the code in editor?? One thing, I have put the additional code of prettyPhoto in header.php file...

Comment: did you try enabling prettyphoto for twenty eleven theme

Comment: OK, Ok, sorry... my problem was with linking of files, I added jquery.prettyPhoto.js before jquer.js so it wasn't working...

Now it's working, all you need is to add the jquery.prettyPhoto.js AFTER the jquery library.